# I have two Mysql servers running on Centos7 . both using different ports. have to manually boot on start.

Tags: mysql, centos7, init.d, chkconfig, my.cnf

I need help . mysql on port 3306 and mysql2 on port 3307.

I copied my.cnf to my2.cnf

I added the following in my2.cnf:

datadir=/var/lib/mysql2
port=3307

cp /etc/init.d/mysql /etc/init.d/mysql2

Added to line 138 in  vi /etc/init.d/mysql2:

--port=*)     port=`echo "$arg" | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//'` ;;

edited line 215:

conf=/etc/my2.cnf

line 257 add -c flag:

parse_server_arguments `$print_defaults $extra_args mysqld server mysql_server mysql.server -c/etc/my2.cnf`

Add port argument to mysql_safe command on line 284:

$bindir/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my2.cnf --datadir="$datadir" --pid-file="$mysqld_pid_file_path" --port="$port" --socket="$datadir"/mysql2.sock $other_args >/dev/null 2>&1 &

added the server to the start up list

chkconfig --add mysql2
chkconfig mysql2 --level 2345 on

currently when i reboot the system and check the status. I get:

[root@localhost ~]# service mysql status

ERROR! MySQL is not running, but lock file (/var/lock/subsys/mysql) exists

[root@localhost ~]# service mysql2 status

ERROR! MySQL is not running, but lock file (/var/lock/subsys/mysql) exists

[root@localhost ~]# service mysql2 start

Starting MySQL... SUCCESS!

[root@localhost ~]# service mysql start

Starting MySQL...... SUCCESS!

what am i doing wrong or do i need to do to get both start on boot

atuomatically? please help.

Comment: Try change `$mysqld_pid_file_path` for each server

Comment: CentOS 7 has switched to using systemd, so it's likely that your init script isn't getting called at boot time but your first instance is getting started by systemd.

Comment: Also, please fix the formatting of your question, it's very hard to read.

Comment: @GregL I thought about that but thought there was a way out. Thank you . and I will do my best to format my question well next time.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file `/etc/init.d/mysql /etc/init.d/mysql2` and find the following section

```
# Lock directory for RedHat / SuSE.
lockdir='/var/lock/subsys'
lock_file_path="$lockdir/mysql"
```

Change `lock_file_path="$lockdir/mysql"` to `lock_file_path="$lockdir/mysql2"`

Should fix the issue :)